# How to loop through an ansible playbook output?

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to get the results for all ip addresses that I am pinging in my playbook. For example, I am trying to ping three different IP addresses and I don't want to manually count how many output.results[] I have to set. Here is my edited playbook:

```
- name: Testing Napalam Ping Module
  hosts: arista
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    output_results: []
  tasks:
    - name: Napalm ping
      napalm_ping:
        provider: "{{creds}}"
        destination: "{{item}}"
      with_items:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 4.2.2.2
      register: output
    - name: I am gonna set the output as a fact
      set_fact:
        ping_results: "{{output.results[1].item}}"
    - name: I am gonna print out the ping_results fact
      debug:
        var: ping_results
    - name: I am gonna set the output as a fact
      set_fact:
        packet_loss: "{{output.results[1].results.success}}"
    - name: I am gonna print out the packet_loss fact
      debug:
        var: packet_loss
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ping_results}} is pingable from {{ansible_host}} with {{item.key}} =  {{item.value}} out of 5 packets"
      with_dict: "{{packet_loss}}"
      when: "item.key == 'packet_loss'"
```

and here is the output:

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [pynet-sw5] => (item={'value': 0, 'key': u'packet_loss'}) => {
    "msg": "1.1.1.1 is pingable from arista5.twb-tech.com with packet_loss =  0 out of 5 packets"
}
ok: [pynet-sw6] => (item={'value': 0, 'key': u'packet_loss'}) => {
    "msg": "1.1.1.1 is pingable from arista6.twb-tech.com with packet_loss =  0 out of 5 packets"
}
ok: [pynet-sw7] => (item={'value': 4, 'key': u'packet_loss'}) => {
    "msg": "1.1.1.1 is pingable from arista7.twb-tech.com with packet_loss =  4 out of 5 packets"
}
ok: [pynet-sw8] => (item={'value': 1, 'key': u'packet_loss'}) => {
    "msg": "1.1.1.1 is pingable from arista8.twb-tech.com with packet_loss =  1 out of 5 packets"
```

since I set the fact for output.results[1] manually I can see only 1.1.1.1 results but I want to see the results for all three ip addresses? is there a way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html) module in a playbook as follows

```
- name: Testing Napalam Ping Module
  hosts: arista
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Napalm ping and debug
      include_tasks: napalm-tasks.yml
      with_items:
        - 1.1.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 4.2.2.2
      loop_control:
        loop_var: destination_host
```

and place all other relevant tasks in a `napalm-tasks.yml` to loop over them to ping and debug the output:

```
- name: Napalm ping
  napalm_ping:
    provider: "{{ creds }}"
    destination: "{{ destination_host }}"
  register: output

- name: I am gonna set the output as a fact
  set_fact:
    ping_results: "{{ output }}"

- name: I am gonna print out the ping_results fact
  debug:
    var: ping_results

- name: I am gonna set the output as a fact
  set_fact:
    packet_loss: "{{ output.results.success }}"

- name: I am gonna print out the packet_loss fact
  debug:
    var: packet_loss

- debug:
    msg: "{{ ping_results }} is pingable from {{ ansible_host }} with {{ item.key }} =  {{ item.value }} out of 5 packets"
  with_dict: "{{ packet_loss }}"
  when: "item.key == 'packet_loss'"
```

Comment: sorry I did not get how that is going to help to get same results for all three Ip addresses? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I updated and included some more details.